# Has anyone come up with a fix line continuation (Python-style) in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: python, sublimetext, sublimetext2

The issue I am referring to is the indentation behavior of lists and other things in Python when on two lines. The result I am looking for is for Sublime to automatically indent like this example, making the code a little prettier:

```
def testmethod(argument1, argument2,
               argument3, argument4):
    pass
```

But in Sublime, when you press enter after line 1, and then type the remaining arguments, this happens:

```
def testmethod(argument1, argument2,
    argument3, argument4):
    pass
```

Obviously, this isn't very readable (and uncompliant with PEP 8 style conventions).
I Googled around and found a few unresolved threads, no solutions. Running latest version of Sublime Text 2, on a Mac. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does not happen for me. Are you indenting using spaces?

Comment: I can indent to that level, it just doesn't do that automatically. I was under the impression that most IDEs auto-indented the line continuation to the same level as the first value on the previous line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can (partially) be fixed by adding:

```
"indent_to_bracket": true
```

to your `Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings` file (linux). But unfortunetly it currently only seems to work for `()`, and not `{}[]`.

Comment: I don't suppose there's a similar setting if one prefers double-indentation (rather than indent_to_bracket)?

Comment: PEP8 specifies that indent_to_bracket should only be apply when at least 1 argument was provided on the first line. If not, a single indent should be used (double indent when the next code block will be indented, such as during an if statement). Sublime's indent_to_bracket applies in all situations, which isn't right.